# Update table in jsf

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm doing a **JSF** with **Primefaces**, i have a `poll` in my page, it update a table in every 1 second, but when I am running a function in server-side, the `poll` does not update table. 
Please, let me know how `poll` continues updating the page.
Thanks in advance!

```html
<p:poll interval="1" autoStart="false" update=":acceptedTable"
                    widgetVar="mypoll"></p:poll>

<h:panelGroup id="acceptedTable">
    <p:dataTable value="#{taxiService.acceptedTaxies}" var="item"
        paginator="true" style="width: 10%"
        rendered="#{taxiService.lengthOfList != 0}" rows="10"
        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}">
        <f:facet name="header">Accepted Taxies</f:facet>
        <p:column style="text-align: center;">
            <f:facet name="header">Number plate</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item}"></h:outputText>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:panelGroup>
```

*Running on a Tomcat server*

***Solution: instead of using poll, use JQuery to update the table***

Comment: I don't think that's very efficient. Updating your table every 1 second causes overhead. Have you considered a long polling technique?

Comment: Vere iz de code? Show us!

Comment: Oh, this is an example. Code is not special, so i don't show it here!

Comment: seriously?! you expect answers to your question without showing any code?

Comment: If you try setting your poll at a slower interval, are you getting better results?  You might be asking to poll to quicky and requests don't get terminated on your server?

Comment: Yes, i'm running on tomcat server, I want update acceptedTable when i'm running a function on server, this function is multithreading, so it spends a lot of minutes to perform.

Comment: That might be the source of your problem.  If you are `poll`ing faster then the function can complete, it will not update.  As for the code setup, without testing it seems fine.

Comment: So do you have any solution for this problem. The polling will run when i click a button to run a multithreading function, when it terminate, polling will stop! This is reason i left 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

Your `poll` is not calling a function.

Try something of the sort :

```html
<p:poll interval="15" listener="#{yourBean.yourFunction}" update=":acceptedTable" />
```

The `listener` is what will call your backing bean to execute your function.  Try setting it up with a simple counter as in the [PrimeFaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf) to see if it is actually calling your function.  Then you can replace it with your own function.  If it works with the counter and not with your function, then the problem is not with the `poll`ing.

Comment: Oh, now i have free time, i found solution 2 3 days ago: instead of using poll, i use jQuery to reload the table and it works :), Thanks for your help.